# How to prove that $X^4+8X^3+X^2+2X+5$ is irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to prove that $X^4+8X^3+X^2+2X+5$ is irreducible on $\mathbb Q[X]$?

I can try to find $a,b,c,d$ such that

$$X^4+8X^3+X^2+2X+5=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$$ 
and prove that $a,b,c,d\notin\mathbb Q$ and find $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$X^4+8X^3+X^2+2X+5=(X-a)(X^3+bX^2+cX+d)$$
and prove that $a,b,c,d\notin \mathbb Q$, but it's really long and I would like to know if there is an other method.

Comment: Can't you use the rational root theorem for the second case?

Comment: I don't know this theorem so I don't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, by the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), no rational number other than $\pm 1, \pm 5$ can be a root of the given polynomial $f$, and evaluating quickly shows that none of these are roots, so $f$ has no linear factors.

There are a few strategies to deal with the possibilities of quadratic factors. A monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ iff it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the only possibilities for the constant terms $(b, d)$ (up to relabeling) in
$$X^4 + 8 X^3 + X^2 + 2 X + 5 = (X^2 + aX + b) (X^2 + cX + d)$$
are $(1, 5)$ and $(-1, -5)$. Substituting the first pair and expanding gives the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} a + c &=& 8 \\ ac + 6 &=& 1 \\ 5 a + c &=& 2 \end{array}\right.;$$ solving the first and third equation shows that there is no solution $(a, c)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, and we can treat the second pair similarly. So, there is no factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Remark** Sometimes a good technique for showing that a polynomial $f$ is irreducible is to find a prime $p$ such that $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$. In our case, this is less efficient than the above method, because the smallest such prime for this $f$ is $p = 23$.

On the other hand, in our case this method does immediately give that $f$ has no linear factors more quickly than the Rational Root Theorem, as substitution gives that $$f(0) \equiv f(1) \equiv 1 \bmod 2.$$

Comment: In characteristic 2, $P(X^2)=P(X)^2$.

Comment: But in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, don't we have that $$X^4+X^2+1=(X^2+X+1)^2$$?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I used Maple's *factor()* instead of *Factor()*, I'll patch that up now.

Comment: Where can I find the proof that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ iff is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29

Comment: @idm Any algebra book. It's a consequence of Gauss' lemma about the product of primitive polynomials; from it it can be deduced that if a factorization exists over $\mathbb{Q}$, then a factorization exists over $\mathbb{Z}$. However the result is “a primitive polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible if and only if it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$”. Primitive means that the gcd of the coefficients is $1$.

Comment: @idm In fact the statement, provided that we take the polynomial to be monic, or more generally, primitive, is true for any unique factorization domain (and its respective field of fractions).

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(X)=A(X)B(X)$ a decomposition of your polynomial into quadratics. Observe that
$$
P(X)\equiv X(X^3+3X^2+X+2) \bmod 5
$$
and the deg 3 factor is irreducible mod 5 because it has no roots mod 5. Thus one of the quadratic factors $A, B$ has only one root mod 5, but this is not possible. Hence there's no factorization.

Comment: This is much more efficient than my solution.